# AucTeX multiple master files in same directory?

Tags: auctex

I have two master files in the same directory, one "main.tex" for the main document (includes several files through `\input`) and "test.tex" which I use to compile just a section at a time for testing.

Even while the footer of "test.tex" says

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

When I hit `C-c C-c` (`TeX-command-master`), it compiles "main.tex". How can I get it to compile "test.tex"?

Comment: What does `M-: (TeX-master-file) RET` return in `main.tex` buffer?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `test.tex` buffer.

Comment: Returns `"main"`. May be because I specified `main` initially (upon creation of file) and changed to `t` later. How do I change... is that a buffer variable that I can just change, or is that in one of the generated files in the directory?

Comment: Ah, that was easy. I just set `(setq TeX-master 't)` for test.tex and now works fine. Guess it was just stored as a buffer local variable. Strange that it ignores the footer at the bottom. If you could write your suggestion as an answer, I would like to mark it as correct.

Comment: Please note you [don't need](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/nil-and-t.html) to quote `t` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You previously set the master file of `test.tex` to `main`, and then changed it to `t`.  In order to make the change effective you have to revert the buffer (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `revert-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>), or issue <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> (`TeX-normal-mode`) if you want to exploit file parsing.